# Making two LinearLayouts have 50% of the screen each without using layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm currently doing a special xml layout of a landscape screen, where 4 images are present and 2 LinearLayouts are next to each other with 2 images each. These LinearLayouts I call `linearLayout1` and `linearLayout2`.

`linearLayout1` is marked with blue rectangle:

[image: linearLayout1]

`linearLayout2` is marked with blue rectangle:

[image: linearLayout2]

As you can see, the first one uses ~80% of the screen, while the second one uses what's left. I don't want this of course, I want 50% for each. I can't use `layout_weight` because it's already used in the LinearLayouts themselves (positioning of the two images) and nested weights are bad for performance.

I've tried many different variations, but I simply can't get the two LinearLayouts to have 50% of the screen each. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/db1_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    style="@style/TitleBar" >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/title_logo" />

    <ImageView
        style="@style/TitleBarSeparator"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc" />

    <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/TitleBarAction"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
        android:onClick="onClickAbout"
        android:src="@drawable/title_about" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_container"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mobFoxView" >

    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mobFoxView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:src="@drawable/front_news_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgReleases"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:src="@drawable/front_releases_1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mobFoxView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgArtists"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:src="@drawable/front_artists_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLabels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewDesc"
            android:onClick="onClickFeature"
            android:src="@drawable/front_labels_1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView
    android:id="@+id/mobFoxView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    mode="test"
    publisherId="@string/mobFoxID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would use nested layout_weight anyway. the performance won't be that bad.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, there are two options I see available here.

1. Screw that LINT warning and use the nested weights anyway. Phones are fast and it will make milliseconds worth of a difference since you only inflate layouts once (most of the time).   Having nested layouts is only bad for performance because the inflator needs to make more passes to measure the layouts.
2. Swap your top `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` and align the two children to an invisible `View` in the center like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/center_point"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/left_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/center_point">
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/right_layout"
      android:orientation="horizontal" //default
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/center_point">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 for the LINT warning comment (I've felt that way for a long time). And a reasonable solution

Comment: You're talking about my "top linearlayout", which one do you mean? My top layout is a relativelayout.

Comment: I thought you were asking of ways to divide a layout within a `LinearLayout` without the use of weights.  Since you already have your two layouts in a `RelativeLayout`, then you're already part way to solution #2.  Create a third, invisible, View that's centered in the parent `LinearLayout` and align the other two to that one.

Answer (score 12):

You can set "Weight" for the layouts , like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
```

So each linearlyouts take 50% of the screen. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid using a feature for its intended purpose you probably should consider if your approach is non-ideal... It seems like you're trying to arrange items into rows and columns. Try using a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without layout_weight, put both of those linearlayouts into a parent linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
           <LinearLayout Child 1 />
           <LinearLayout Child 2 />
</LinearLayout>
```

center them using layout_gravity , if the content of those linearlayouts are the same size, they should be the same size

if not, then you could still have a problem

and may need to resize using code