# Is there another way to evenly space views other than using LinearLayouts and layout_weight?

Tags: android

Right now I have views with layout_weight inside another view that also has the same attribute, which causes the outer view to be calculated exponentially. I'm considering nesting another set of views with weights inside of the inner view, but that would cause the outermost view to be calculated more times than I would like. I'm just splitting the areas up evenly (each view within a group all have the same weight), but I want everything to scale properly regardless of what size or DPI the screen is. Is there any other way to efficiently split views within another view?

Comment: Using `layout_weight` is usually the best way to do it. If you aren't seeing the layout you want then it seems you're using `layout_weight` in the wrong places or with the wrong 'weight' values. Post your layout XML and explain how you want the layout to look.

Comment: I think my answer from a similar topic would help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539268/making-two-linearlayouts-have-50-of-the-screen-each-without-using-layout-weight/10539489#10539489

Comment: Note, this only works with evenly divided layouts.  You could do it by nesting more and more and more layouts, but at a certain point it's better than to just use `layout_weight`.

Comment: @DeeV That looks like it could work. I do like how you suggested to just screw the warnings, and I considered that myself, but whenever the phrase "exponentially increases" gets mentioned in regards to measurements or calculations, I get a little leery.

Comment: It could "increase exponentially" if you have layout within layout within layout within layout all using nested weights.  If it takes half a second to load your layout, then you may want to reconsider the design or how you're laying out.  However, the lint warning occurs too often to the point where 90% of them are irrelevant.  Still, you don't really have to handle it until it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeeV's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539268/making-two-linearlayouts-have-50-of-the-screen-each-without-using-layout-weight/10539489#10539489) does a good job of it:

> Swap your top `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` and align the two children to an >invisible `View` in the center like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/center_point"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/left_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/center_point>
    </Linearlayout>


    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/right_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/center_point>
    </Linearlayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```