# Making buttons take equal height and width of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am currently trying to make a view with four buttons that each take up one quarter of the screen. I know you can use android:layout_weight to set the weight so that the extra space on one axis is filled up, but is there a way to set it so that the height and width are evenly distributed among the four buttons using layout_weight? If not, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Put them in two different horizontal layouts placed vertically with equal weights and assign equal weights to the buttons as well.

Comment: Hi, I recently answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20082208/349044). I think this should give   you the information you need :-)

Comment: +1 Aakash Goyal, that idea worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

use table layout and create two rows for 4 buttons,determined the height and width
all of these codes are ( XML code)..
should that will working